# Disable OWIN OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddlewate on the fly

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

How can I disable or skip OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddlewate execution?

Problem: for some requests I don't want to set Principal with claims, but requests have "Authorization" header with Bearer token value.

One of the solution is to create one more middleware and there is remove Authorization header from request.

Answer (score 0):

I need to enable OAuth owin middleware with AuthenticationMode.Passive